# Ordering blog posts from most recent to oldest using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just started using PDO (loving it!). Still trying to learn the basics. Currently I can make a connection and display the data I want. However, I want to display my blog posts from newest to oldest based on the date. Below is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
   while($row = $sth->fetch()) {  ?>
   <ul class="blog article_list large">
       <li>
           <img class="img_frame" src="images/blog_large/post01.jpg" alt="" />
           <article>
               <h2><a href="#"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a></h2>
                    <?php echo $row['slug'] ?> 
               <small class="details">
                    By <a href="#" class="article_author"><?php echo $row['author'] ?></a>
                    on <time datetime="2011-09-28" pubdate="pubdate"><?php echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row['date'])) ?></time>
                    in <a href="#" class="cat"><?php echo $row['category'] ?></a>.
               </small>
            </article>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there a PDO statement to do this?

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` clause in the query you are running before this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, wouldn't that be a part of your SQL? Using `ORDER BY` or some other sorting method? PDO is just a data access layer - you'd do better to sort like that on the database side then just pull the results out as they come.